# Using Teamcity REST API, how to get list of nuget packages using teamcity rest API?

Tags: c#, powershell, continuous-integration, teamcity-9.1

Using this page [Teamcity REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-buildartifacts) I could manage to get status of builds in teamcity.
I also found this library [TeamCitySharp](https://github.com/stack72/TeamCitySharp) to get information about Teamcity builds.
Is there any API that I can use to get list of all Nugget Packages used for each build?
I would appreciate code sample.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a long while since this question was asked, but I've just been searching for the answer and passed this question before I found this:

http://[your_teamcity_instance]/app/rest/builds/id:[buildid]/artifacts/content/.teamcity/nuget/nuget.xml

From the Teamcity REST API, you can retrieve the build id, which when used in the above template will provide you with an XML file, listing the NuGet packages used in a the build.

Comment: Sorry, my first answer and wasn't very clear. I've updated to better explain. The link provided wasn't meant to be a web link, but a link to the OP's (or anyone's) local teamcity instance to get the information they were looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a required step before using this URL? I have sucessfully obtained the buildid but when i launch the url i get a 404